# Download and list saved file to tableview

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

My project work file when i download and list saved files to tableView. But i have problem with file name when i list files to tableView (see picture).

[image]

Here is my cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MainCell"];
    }
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];
    cell.textLabel.text = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString:[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}
```

Another I want to download different files with different extension and save it with original file, but my code save only filename which i set.
And here is my code:

```
- (IBAction)download {

//    NSString* fileToSaveTo = @"file";
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        NSLog(@"Downloading Started");
        NSString *urlToDownload = @"http://chingfong.com/Icon.png";
        NSURL  *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlToDownload];
        NSData *urlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        if ( urlData )
        {
            NSArray       *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
            NSString  *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

            NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"Image.png"];

            //saving is done on main thread
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                [urlData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
                NSLog(@"File Saved !");
            });
        }

    });

}
```

Comment: What is the problem? What isn't working how you would like?

Comment: I want tableView only show "filename.extension" not all Directory. And i want to download different file with different extension. Example in my project when i download a PFD file but it save with 123.png

Comment: So why do you use `documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString...`

Comment: I edited my code to NSString* theFileName = [filePathsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = theFileName; and now it work

Comment: And i want to download different file with different extension. Example in my project when i download a PFD file but it save with 123.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A.

Don't use `documentsDirectory stringByAppendingString` to create the cell text, just use the file name.

B.

Don't hard code the save file name, instead use:

```
NSString *fileName = [urlToDownload lastPathComponent];
```

Comment: so i need to remove NSString  *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory,@"Image.png"]; and add your code?

Comment: you need to change the 'Image.png' part to use `fileName`. You should also use `stringByAppendingPathComponent:`.